# Failed to resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED pusher.min.js

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher

i m working on laravel websocket, it runs fine on my local, but when i deploy to server which doesn't has internet connection it failed, when i m trying to access http:localhost/laravel-websockets. Where i can make pusher.min.js offline?